# Is second-order generic type inference suported in modern Python (3.11+)?

Tags: python-3.x, generics, types

First things first, I'm very much a n00b in Python programming. My background is in Haskell, Ocaml, modern C++, F#, C#: all of these are strictly typed languages with different approach to generic typing. I'm mentioning this to justify my request to explain the answer in a bit more detail that you would to someone more versed in Python.

I'm using VS Code with pylance which includes pyright as the typechecker.

#### Motivation

I am coding an algorithm which may be backed by one of a few ML frameworks. Let's, for the sake of an example, consider TensorFlow and NumPy. I've added a compatibility layer, a class (currently abstract and derived from ABC, but I'm not hanging on to this). You do not need to know anything at all about these frameworks; the model is indeed simple; framework is a library of functions and types, just like any Python package, with the following :

- Each framework has a concept of an multidimensional array (NDAr).
- Types of these are, in general, unrelated.
- Methods take a type-stubbed `Union[]` of covariant adjoint of NDAr's type, and other stuff that can be converted to NDAr, such as Python list, explicitly available in the .pyi context (not in .py, tho, for some frameworks). Let's call this type alias TyCoNDAr. Each framework defines a type alias for this type; I'm introducing the id only in the problem description.
- Let's consider only return values that are either contravariant quotient adjoint of NDAr's type, or simply the NDAr's type. Let's ignore contravariance, and label its type alias TyNDAr.

I'm leaving out the fact that the NDAr also has a datatype of its (scalar) elements, and certain functions may change it. Annotating that is “nice to have” but complicates the issue. I may post it as a question later, when I have solved this issue, or am convinced this is not yet solvable. I'm mainly running into bugs when an argument of invalid, non-implicitly-convertible type is passed.

Next, we'll distill the problem to the simplest case, the compatibility class having the single function `exp(x)` which returns element-wise exponentiation of its input of an arbitrary dimensioned NDAr. Also, we'll use absolute minimum of two frameworks in this example, NumPy and TensorFlow. These framework fill our abstractions as shown in the table:

| Framework | TyCoNDAr | TyNDAr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NumPy | Np.ArrayLike | Np.NDArray |
| TensorFlow | Tf._TensorCompatible | Tf.Tensor |

Now to the concrete toy example *which does not work*. The `abstract_framework.pyi` annotations look like (I'm always using capitalised namespace aliases for typing annotations):

```py
import numpy.typing as Np # Types live in own package
import tensorflow as Tf   # Types available only in .pyi context.

type Tensor = Np.NDArray | tf.Tensor
type CoTensor = Np.ArrayLike | tf._TensorCompatible

class AbstractFramework(ABC):
  @classmethod
  def exp(cls, x: CoTensor) -> Tensor: ...
```

There are, obviously, corresponding real classes `class AbstractFramework(ABC):` in a .py file, with `exp` decorated `@abstract`, and `class NumpyFramework(AbstractFramework):` and `class TensorFlowFramework(AbstractFramework):` with implementation, calling respective implementations of `exp`, and without type annotations. There are no problems in runtime, but pyright gets extremely angry at me.

The problem is `type CoTensor` is too lax, and `type Tensor` resist narrowing where the framework is type-annotated as `AbstractFramework`, all the rest of code in fact sees.

The common solution I've seen is using @overload. In this case, the `.pyi` file changes to

```py
import numpy.typing as Np # Types live in own package
import tensorflow as Tf   # Types available only on .pyi context.

class AbstractFramework(ABC):
  @overload
  @classmethod
  def exp(cls, x: Np.ArrayLike) -> Np.NDArray: ...
  @overload
  @classmethod
  def exp(cls, x: tf._TensorCompatible) -> tf.Tensor: ...
```

Unfortunately, this is not a maintainable solution when there are 5 supported frameworks and over 30 class methods in the `AbstractFramework`.

#### Known other language solutions

The common solution to the problem is higher-order generics: the compiler (or type checker) selects a generic class *not explicit* in code, guided by the types, sometimes referred to as *generic trait types,* never mentioned by name, but selected by type deduction rules. One example is C++ Template Deductions.

The *completely non-working, pseudo-annotation* .pyi file looks like this:

```py
import numpy.typing as Np # Types live in own package
import tensorflow as Tf   # Types available only on .pyi context.

class NumpyTraits:
  type TyNDAr = Np.NDArray
  type TyCoNDAr = Np.NDArray | Np.ArrayLike

class TensorFlowTraits:
  type TyNDAr = tf.Tensor
  type TyCoNDAr = tf.Tensor | tf._TensorCompatible

class AbstractFramework(ABC):
  @classmethod
  def exp[B:«indication which B's are to consider»](cls, x: B.TyCoNDAr) -> B.TyNDAr: ...
```

The idea is that the typechecker attempts to find the best matching `B` among the traits classes s.t. `x` is the best match to `B.CoTensor` and substitutes the `B` to deduce the output type `B.Tensor`.

Trait type deduction is by far not the only known solution to the problem; I'm mentioning it only as an example.

#### Question

Is there any way to implements something like the above in the modern Python? In other words, *known types are grouped* in some way, known to the typechecker as possible generic matches to arguments. Having selected the matching group, the typechecker substitutes the concrete return type (the `B.TyNDAr` type in the pseudo-example above) from the same group.

Or, more concretely, a series of language constructs amounting to a list of rules with the semantics “when the arguments typed as TCoNDAr best match Np.NDArray or Np.NDArrayLike, turn the abstract/generic return type TNDAr into the concrete tyle Np.NDArray”